# JavaFX Clipping an ImageView to an Ellipse within an AnchorPane

Tags: java, javafx

I have been building an app where I want to display one big image inside an ellipse to mimic the roof of a planetarium.
Clipping the ImageView displaying image to the ellipse with `myImageView.setClip(myEllipse)` has worked gracefully until the last version of my app where the AnchorPane I am adding the Ellipse into seems not to appreciate my clipping an image within it.

The error I get for the line `myImageView.setClip(myEllipse)` is the following:

Caused by:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Node's clip set to incorrect value
>   (node already connected, node  = ImageView@a13b0a6, clip =
>   ObjectProperty [bean: ImageView@a13b0a6, name: clip, value: null]).

What I understand is that I am creating some kind of loop within the scene graph, but i can't figure out where.

This is my code (the whole interface is "hardcoded")

```
package opinarium3;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.image.Image;
import javafx.scene.image.ImageView;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import static javafx.scene.layout.VBox.setMargin;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class Opinarium3 extends Application {
    private Ellipse ceiling;
    private ImageView ceiling_image;
    private VBox nav;
    private HBox buttonSet;
    private Label presentation_title;
    private TextArea info;
    private Button previous;
    private Button comment;
    private Button next;
    private double sx;
    private double sy;
    private DoubleProperty coordX = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);
    private DoubleProperty coordY = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0);

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene primaryScene = new Scene(root, 900, 800);
        primaryScene.getStylesheets().add(Opinarium3.class.getResource("Opinarium3.css").toExternalForm());
        initializeCeiling(root);
        initializeNav(root);
        initializeContent();
        initializePrimaryStage(primaryStage, primaryScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initializePrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage, Scene primaryScene) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Planetario de San José - Cartelera de Presentaciones");
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(900);
        primaryStage.setHeight(800);
        primaryStage.minHeightProperty().setValue(800);
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().setValue(900);
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void initializeCeiling(AnchorPane root) {
        ceiling = new Ellipse();
        ceiling.centerXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().multiply(0.5));
        ceiling.centerYProperty().setValue(0);
        ceiling.radiusXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().multiply(0.8));
        ceiling.radiusYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().multiply(0.6));
        root.getChildren().add(ceiling);
    }

    private void initializeNav(AnchorPane root) {
        nav = new VBox();
        initializeControls(nav);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(nav, 20.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(nav, 120.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(nav, 120.0);
        root.getChildren().add(nav);
    }

    private void initializeControls(VBox nav) {
        info = new TextArea();
        setMargin(info, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));
        info.setWrapText(true);
        info.setEditable(false);
        buttonSet = new HBox();
        initializeButtonSet(nav);
        presentation_title = new Label("Título de la Presentación");
        presentation_title.setId("titulo");
        nav.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);
        nav.getChildren().addAll(presentation_title, info, buttonSet);
    }

    private void initializeButtonSet(VBox nav) {
        previous = new Button("<");
        comment = new Button("Doy mi opinión");
        comment.setId("comment_button");
        next = new Button(">");
        buttonSet.spacingProperty().bind(nav.widthProperty().multiply(0.15));
        buttonSet.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setMargin(buttonSet, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));
        buttonSet.getChildren().addAll(previous, comment, next);
    }

    private void initializeContent() throws IOException {
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/opinarium3/media/joyas/joyas.txt"));
            String title = br.readLine();
            String length = br.readLine();
            String description = br.readLine();
            this.presentation_title.setText(title);
            this.info.setText("\n"+description+"\n\nDuración: "+length);
            br.close();


            ceiling_image = new ImageView(new Image(Opinarium3.class.getResourceAsStream("media/joyas/joyas.jpg")));
            ceiling_image.setClip(ceiling);
            /*
            ceiling_image.setOnMousePressed(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t) {
                    sx = t.getSceneX() - coordX.doubleValue();
                    sy = t.getSceneY() - coordY.doubleValue();
                }
            });
            ceiling_image.setOnMouseDragged(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                @Override
                public void handle(MouseEvent t){
                    if(t.getSceneX() - sx < 0){
                        coordX.setValue(t.getSceneX() - sx);
                    }
                    if(t.getSceneY() - sy < 0){
                        coordY.setValue(t.getSceneY() - sy);
                    }
                }
            });
            ceiling_image.xProperty().bind(coordX);
            ceiling_image.yProperty().bind(coordY);
                    */
        }catch(IOException e){}
    }
}
```

Comment: For your next question, please try to post code as an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); i.e. minimal code which is still executable, does not rely on local files and only has enough code to demonstrate the issue.  Most importantly, don't swallow exceptions in a catch block without printing them or re-throwing them.  Thanks

Comment: I understand... I will try to keep all of those in mind. Thank you for the observation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image: screenshot]

You can only use the shape once in the scene, you can't have it set as both a clip and added as a child of an element.

You are adding the clip to the scene instead of the item being clipped to the scene.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.image.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Ellipse;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import static javafx.scene.layout.VBox.setMargin;

public class Opinarium3 extends Application {
    private Ellipse ceiling;
    private ImageView ceiling_image;
    private VBox nav;
    private HBox buttonSet;
    private Label presentation_title;
    private TextArea info;
    private Button previous;
    private Button comment;
    private Button next;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        AnchorPane root = new AnchorPane();
        Scene primaryScene = new Scene(root, 900, 800);
        initializeCeiling(root);
        initializeNav(root);
        initializeContent(root);
        initializePrimaryStage(primaryStage, primaryScene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void initializePrimaryStage(Stage primaryStage, Scene primaryScene) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Planetario de San José - Cartelera de Presentaciones");
        primaryStage.setScene(primaryScene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(900);
        primaryStage.setHeight(800);
        primaryStage.minHeightProperty().setValue(800);
        primaryStage.minWidthProperty().setValue(900);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    private void initializeCeiling(AnchorPane root) {
        ceiling = new Ellipse();
        ceiling.centerXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().multiply(0.5));
        ceiling.centerYProperty().setValue(0);
        ceiling.radiusXProperty().bind(root.widthProperty().multiply(0.8));
        ceiling.radiusYProperty().bind(root.heightProperty().multiply(0.6));
    }

    private void initializeNav(AnchorPane root) {
        nav = new VBox();
        initializeControls(nav);
        AnchorPane.setBottomAnchor(nav, 20.0);
        AnchorPane.setLeftAnchor(nav, 120.0);
        AnchorPane.setRightAnchor(nav, 120.0);
        root.getChildren().add(nav);
    }

    private void initializeControls(VBox nav) {
        info = new TextArea();
        setMargin(info, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));
        info.setWrapText(true);
        info.setEditable(false);
        buttonSet = new HBox();
        initializeButtonSet(nav);
        presentation_title = new Label("Título de la Presentación");
        presentation_title.setId("titulo");
        nav.alignmentProperty().setValue(Pos.CENTER);
        nav.getChildren().addAll(presentation_title, info, buttonSet);
    }

    private void initializeButtonSet(VBox nav) {
        previous = new Button("<");
        comment = new Button("Doy mi opinión");
        comment.setId("comment_button");
        next = new Button(">");
        buttonSet.spacingProperty().bind(nav.widthProperty().multiply(0.15));
        buttonSet.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        setMargin(buttonSet, new Insets(10, 0, 0, 0));
        buttonSet.getChildren().addAll(previous, comment, next);
    }

    private void initializeContent(AnchorPane root) {
        Image image = new Image(
                "http://takeinsocialmedia.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/landscape-art-painting-wallpaper-images-photos-0517193352.jpg"
        );
        ceiling_image = new ImageView(image);
        ceiling_image.setClip(ceiling);
        root.getChildren().add(ceiling_image);
    }
}
```